# Playing Cards in Java

Tags: java, enums

My question is I have to write a program in java that creates different playing cards 
and adequately demonstrates the methods of Playing Card.

how to write equals methods for this program? The equals method should be overridden  I kind of know How to write a toString method.

It does not want any Mutator methods.  it needs Other methods.

That's all I need help on. If you can help me that would be great and I thank for you time for helping me.

Comment: it sounds more that what you need is a tutorial on enumerations.

Comment: If you have problem creating methods and constructors, you _really_ need to start with [java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I feel that this link seems relevant to your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is in the tutorial for [Java 5 Enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)
Also your question on equals/hashmap is in the [Java FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for the Rank enum.

```
 public enum Rank {
DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE;
 }
```

Here is the PlayingCard constructor.

```
 public PlayingCard(Rank r, Suit s) {
     //... construction code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping all of you yea and this was my homework question.  the reason that I asked this question was I really had no Idea what I was suppose to do.  That's Why I needed help

Comment: How should I write equals method in this problem? If you have any Idea that would be great thank you